# checked property is not setting to true inside treeviewitem of a filtered result in ngx-treeview component

Tags: ngx-treeview

My config:

```
config = TreeviewConfig.create({
hasAllCheckBox: false,
hasFilter: true,
hasCollapseExpand: false,
decoupleChildFromParent: true,
maxHeight: 400
});
```

I am using the inbuilt filter to find specific items in tree structure. But when I am selecting (selecting the checkbox) an item from the filtered tree structure, the checked property for that particular treeviewitem is not setting to true in the treeviewItem collection. How can resolve this issue?

Comment: see what comments?

Comment: Can someone please let us know a work around to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a `Treeview item list` named as *treeList* and you have a set of items you want to **check** in an array named *checkList*.

All you have to do is to iterate through the array list of specific IDs that is to be checked in the tree and use the `TreeviewHelper.findItemInList` and `checked` properties to set those items checked.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.checkList.length; i++) {
    TreeviewHelper.findItemInList(this.treeList, this.checkList[i]).checked = true;
}
```

For further reference, you can check [this](https://github.com/leovo2708/ngx-treeview/issues/42).